# Sequentially execute a bunch of WinJS promises from an array

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, coffeescript, promise, winjs

I have an array of URLs that I want to download sequentially, 2 URLs at the time.

`var urls = [url1,url2,url3,url4,url5];`

The loop should download all the URLs using some async function, 2 urls at the time in the order they appear in the array.
The basic sequential loop is done using `.reduce` that works like this:

```
preloadPromise = urls.reduce(function(p, url) {
  return p.then(WinJS.Utilities.Scheduler.schedulePromiseBelowNormal).then(function() {
    return preloadOneAsync(url);
  }).then(null, function(error) {
    if (error.name !== "Canceled") {
      logger.error("Could not create preloaded " + url, error);
    }
  });
}, WinJS.Promise.as());
```

Now I want to introduce parallel downloads of 2 URLs at the same time.

So it would download: [url1,url2] then [url3,url4] and finally [url5]

Also the result of the function should be the results of every download promise, similar to how `WinJS.Promise.join` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's abstract out the function to break the array into tuples

```
function chunkBy(array, n) {
    var chunks = [];
    for (var i=0; i<array.length; i+=n)
        chunks.push(array.slice(i, n));
    return chunks;
}
```

and the function that does the work for each item:

```
function tryToLoad(url) {
    return WinJS.Utilities.Scheduler.schedulePromiseBelowNormal() // not sure
    .then(function() {  return preloadOneAsync(url); })
    .then(null, function(error) {
        if (error.name !== "Canceled") {
            logger.error("Could not create preloaded " + url, error);
        }
    });
}
```

A function that does the work for multiple items in parallel would be just

```
function loadAll(urls) {
    return WinJS.Promise.join(urls.map(tryToLoad));
}
```

so we can now use this in the generation of the sequence:

```
preloadPromise = chunkBy(urls, 2).reduce(function(p, urls) {
    return p.then(function(prevResults) {
        return loadAll(urls).then(function(results) {
            return prevResults.concat(results);
        });
    });
}, WinJS.Promise.as([]));
```

The array of results is passed through the `p` chain, always growing after each step.

Comment: Thanks, you seem to be the `Promise` guy :) One thing though: I believe WinJS.Promise.join fails if any of the promises fails, so I wouldn't know which URLs to retry after a couple of seconds.

Comment: Only one of [those guys](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/promise/topusers) :-) Yes, `join` fails if any of the promises in the array fails, but that's not relevant here - `tryToLoad` *never* fails, as it catches all errors. The error handler may return an object that indicates which URL failed, though.

Comment: But the error handler must not return a failed promise like with `return WinJS.Promise.wrapError(error)`

Comment: Yes, it must return a *result* (saying that something should be repeated), instead of failing itself. Currently it just returns `undefined`, which works fine, but is not very informative.

Comment: how would I break the `.reduce` call and skip the remaining items in the array in case `tryToLoad` was canceled?

Comment: You usually wouldn't; the `reduce` has already happened when any `tryToLoad` had been cancelled. Rejecting one promise in the chain will automatically (and quite efficiently) reject all the others, so you don't need to do that explicitly. If any used promise is already rejected during building the chain, you can use *synchronous inspection*.